# Should a GitHub issue with a "question" label should be closed once the question is answered at the comment section?

Tags: github, issue-tracking

In GitHub, it is possible to ask a question as an issue. There is even a default label named as "question" for issues like this.

Supposing this question as an issue is answered with a text comment inside the issue's comment section, should the issue be closed?

In theory, I would say "yes", since the "problem" is done.

In practice, my experience is that if the issue is still open I believe it is easier for people to see it before asking the same thing again and again.

Your thoughts on it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This highly depends on your organization's workflow, and integration with other tools, but generally: yes, it should be closed, and if the issue is a common question, it [should be pinned](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/pinning-an-issue-to-your-repository) for visibility. If it's something that leads to a longer discussion but can't be 100% resolved either through an answer or a code change, it could instead be [moved to a discussion](https://docs.github.com/en/discussions/managing-discussions-for-your-community/moderating-discussions#converting-an-issue-to-a-discussion).

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how a post can get 3 downvotes but the answer gets 3 upvotes. Do you why I am getting so many downvotes @ZacAnger?

Comment: Your question got downvotes because technically it's off-topic for this site, but I thought that regardless it's a good question that could come up in a search later, so deserved an answer. Sometimes it's hard to balance out the urge to enforce the rules with the urge to answer an interesting question :)

Comment: Would recommend a different website in the Stack Exchange Network?